# How to fix OOM error encountered when performing logical replication through jdbc?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, database-replication

I am developing a java application that uses test_decoding + jdbc driver to do PG logical replication. The main code comes from the [PG documentation](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/replication.html#logical-replication).

```java
PGReplicationStream stream =
        replConnection.getReplicationAPI()
            .replicationStream()
            .logical()
            .withSlotName("demo_logical_slot")
            .withSlotOption("include-xids", true)
            .withSlotOption("skip-empty-xacts", true)
            .withSlotOption("include-timestamp", "on")
            .withStatusInterval(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .start();

    while (true) {
      //non blocking receive message
      ByteBuffer msg = stream.readPending();

      if (msg == null) {
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(10L);
        continue;
      }

      int offset = msg.arrayOffset();
      byte[] source = msg.array();
      int length = source.length - offset;
      System.out.println(new String(source, offset, length));

      //feedback
      stream.setAppliedLSN(stream.getLastReceiveLSN());
      stream.setFlushedLSN(stream.getLastReceiveLSN());
    }
```

The above code works fine for most scenarios.

However, `stream.readPending()` will throw OOM error when a large transaction commit to the postgresql.

In my case, I update 432629 rows in one transaction, and the java server(2 CPU + 4GB memory) throw OOM error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
         at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.receive(PGStream.java:445)
         at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processCopyResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1170)
         at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.readFromCopy(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1035)
         at org.postgresql.core.v3.CopyDualImpl.readFromCopy(CopyDualImpl.java:41)
         at org.postgresql.core.v3.replication.V3PGReplicationStream.receiveNextData(V3PGReplicationStream.java:155)
         at org.postgresql.core.v3.replication.V3PGReplicationStream.readInternal(V3PGReplicationStream.java:124)
         at org.postgresql.core.v3.replication.V3PGReplicationStream.readPending(V3PGReplicationStream.java:78)
```

So my question is how to fix the OOM error except increase the java server hardware.

Comment: Just a remark: you copied from them `new String(source, offset, length)`; better: `new String(source, offset, length, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)`. As for instance not every byte sequence is valid UTF-8, should the default encoding be UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks for the remark. I find a bug in the java application which cause OOM error, and the ```stream.readPending()``` works well.